# getPlacePredictions vs getPredictions, google maps autocomplete service clarification

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the difference between `autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions` and `autocompleteService.getPredictions` in the Google Maps Autocomplete Service? I've created tests for these here, but they seem to be returning the same things:

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/google-places-tests

Answer (score 5):

For [`AutocompleteService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompleteService) in the `google.maps.places` JavaScript library:

[`AutocompleteService#getPlacePredictions()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest) appears to be used for more detailed searches when you only want places returned. Meanwhile, [`AutocompleteService#getQueryPredictions()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#QueryAutocompletionRequest) returns results that may not represent actual places (as such, its `place_id` property is optional), so you can do a looser search and suggest queries to the user. Its returned prediction terms may include ["categorical terms", such as "restaurant"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#QueryAutocompletePrediction.terms).

`getPlacePredictions()` takes in [`AutocompletionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletePrediction) while `getQueryPredictions()` takes in [`QueryAutocompletionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#QueryAutocompletePrediction). The former has these properties that the latter does not, *all of which are optional*: `componentRestrictions`, `offset`, `origin`, `sessionToken`, `types`.

`getPlacePredictions()` passes [`AutocompletePrediction[]`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletePrediction) into your callback function while `getQueryPredictions()` passes in [`QueryAutocompletePrediction[]`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#QueryAutocompletePrediction). The former *object* has these properties that the latter does not: `distance_meters`, `structured_formatting`, `types`.

Comment: This does not address the question of what `getPredictions` does.

Comment: It's been a while, but iirc that method call is no longer part of the API and thus has no documentation available. It's an old question.

Comment: Sure it's old, but some of us are coming here because they are working on legacy code. Explaining what another function that wasn't asked about just muddies the situation. We have code that uses `getPredictions` and we are trying to understand how that works before we can replace it.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same thing.

```
kx.prototype.getPlacePredictions = function(a, b) { _.G("places_impl", (0, _.p)(function() { this.b.getPlacePredictions(a, b) }, this)) };
kx.prototype.getPredictions = kx.prototype.getPlacePredictions;
```

'getPrediction' method is directly assigned to 'getPlacePrediction' in the JavaScript code from Google API

Answer (score 2):

I don't see getPredictions documented, perhaps it is an older syntax that is still supported for compatability. You should only use documented functions.

[AutocompleteService in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService)

> getPlacePredictions(request:AutocompletionRequest, callback:function(Array, PlacesServiceStatus))
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Retrieves place autocomplete predictions based on the supplied autocomplete request.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#summary-of-classes):

Call `getPlacePredictions()` to retrieve matching places, or call `getQueryPredictions()` to retrieve matching places plus suggested search terms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a diffrence in the results:
getPlacePredictions() retrieves matching places
getQueryPredictions() retrieves matching places plus suggested search terms.

Source:
https://blog.woosmap.com/implement-and-optimize-autocomplete-with-google-places-api